# Nginx Pagespeed Module: What is "Ngx_pagespeed Slow write operation on file /usr/share/nginx/ngx_pagespeed_cache..." in error logs and how to fix?

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, mod-pagespeed

I am running an Ubuntu 20.04 LEMP server with the pagespeed module for Nginx in a business environment. In my `/var/log/nginx/error.log` I am seeing the following error:

```
[ngx_pagespeed 1.15.0.0-8811] Slow write operation on file /usr/share/nginx/ngx_pagespeed_cache/v3/mcmo.is/https,3A/,2Fwww.mcmo.is/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/McMo-Art-Tryclops-1-scaled.webp,.tempqfKyZe: 61.512ms; configure SlowFileLatencyUs to change threshold
```

What exactly does this mean, and how can I improve/fix things so that this error no longer appears?

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Its called "serverfault". I'm running a SERVER! I'm pretty sure this applies buddy. You don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: Here is the text you get when you create new question: To improve the chances of your question staying open and getting an answer, make sure that it is about **managing information technology systems in a business environment**. If your question concerns personal equipment, try asking on Super User instead.

Comment: Also check this page: https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @RomeoNinov I added "in a business environment" in my original post since this server is being run for business. Thanks for being rediculous man.